# Updating Java JAR file

Tags: java, jar, applet, sign

I have updated an applet JAR file, and I have uploaded the modified JAR file on the server, now when the clients opens the applet, some of them see the new modifications and some are not, I was enforced to clear the JAVA cache on the client machine in order to download the new JAR by force.

Why this problem happened? Is there anything prevents downloading the JAR file????

Comment: Are you aware that applet is a legacy technology and it'll be deprecated in java 9 ?

Comment: yes, I'm aware about that, and I have already converted the applet to application, but my boss still insist to continue with applet for a little bit of time